# Colimits and epimorphisms.

Tags: category-theory

I am working on a project, and I need to know the proof of this:

> Any functor which preserves all colimits preserves epimorphisms.

So could you please tell me how or where I can find the proof for this corollary?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This follows from the following fact. $e : X \to Y$ is an epimorphism if and only if 
[image: pushout]

is a pushout. This should be very easy to verify. Pushouts are finite colimits and therefore if a functor preserves colimits it will map pushouts to pushouts and therefore epis to epis.

Comment: @Dan If this answers your question then you should accept it as an answer (click the tick on the left below the downvote button).